# Activity is not closed on clicking back button of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Refer Below Image,
[image]
I want to go back to the previous activity.
But on clicking the back button on toolbar,Nothing is happening.
I have used the following code to achieve that still no luck.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
       if(item.getItemId() == R.id.home)
       {
           finish();
       }
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: make it `android.R.id.home`

Comment: You need to use getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);,
    and getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 3):

## In your `OnCreate` method

```
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_setting);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

## In your `onOptionsItemSelected` method

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onBackPressed()` method on your Activity. And super this. And when click back button call to `this.onBackPressed()`.
Update code for this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        this.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Remember `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`